# Simulate GPS IMU With Quadcopter Swarm?

Tags: matlab, navigation, gps, imu

I have multiple drones work in swarm formation, i made the quadcopter model and the swarm one.
Until now i have the swarm moving in a formation leader-follower and track a predefined trajectory based on PID Controller.
What i need help is how to add  GPS, IMU sensors model to my model?

Comment: I do not understand fully your question. This site is about programming, but it seems you are asking about hardware. We have sister sites (top right icon) on Arduino (also on raspberry pi), on electrinics and on drones. They may be more on topic. Note: if you use the same GPS module you will get precise relative positions, but if you buy GPS module with differential GPS you get more precise results (you should just syncronize with the master). With dualband GPS and you can have centimeter precision (compared to master).

Comment: Now reading the title, it seems much more a simulation? Could you add more details on your question?

Comment: Thanks for replay, what i want to do is simulate swarm of drones by using Matlab and want to simulate the imu and gps sensors